# What is the best way to reintegrate a SVN branch back into trunk (in Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, svn, branching-and-merging

I want to merge my current SVN branch back into our trunk. There aren't that many changes but a lot of files have been impacted.

I selected the project root in Eclipse.  I want to use the merge type/ Reintegrate a branch.

Would it be less error prone to use the same Reintegrate branch but on a package per package basis?  Do I have to go through each modification one by one?

Are there any other svn commands I should do before merging?

Answer (score 0):

The Reintegrate a branch tool is fine. Do it on the project level to save time I've done this several times already without any issues. That also sets the SVN properties so that you can track the reinteration afterwards. You don't have to run any other SVN commands.

Comment: Thanks you. That's what I'll do.